# Is it possible to take a tuple returned from a func and pass it into another func?

Tags: tuples, swift

Is it possible to take a tuple returned from a func and pass it into another func without introducing another variable?

This is the only way I can come up with:

```
func getTuple() -> (x:Float, y:Float) {
    return (0, 0)
}

func processTuple(x:Float, y:Float) {

}

let pt = getTuple()
processTuple(pt.x, pt.y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

function can take tuple as argument

```
func getTuple() -> (x:Float, y:Float) {
    return (0, 0)
}

func processTuple(t:(Float, Float)) {

}

processTuple(getTuple())
```